# Selenium Increase timeout for element click

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Suppose a I have a page that has a button. When I click on this button a server processing is done, but it may take more than 60 seconds to do so.
Then I make a script to click on this button and a timeout exception is then thrown:

The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL  click timed out after 60 seconds.

Then I have tried to set these timeouts, none of them worked:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:27541/");
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)); 
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
driver.FindElement(By.Id("button1")).Click();
```

How can I do that? 
I need to increase the timeout just for this button.

This solution worked, but I cant change the timeout for the entire script:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), new FirefoxProfile(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```

Selenium NuGet package version: 2.53.1
Firefox version: 46.0.1

Comment: After you click this button, is their any indication on the user interface. Like the button being disabled or some image rotating. If so you can setup a webdriverwait on this element to become enabled or the roating image to become invisible. It will be an explicit wait just for this and not affect your script.

Comment: @Grasshopper, the problem is that the Click method halts the execution.

Comment: Why can't you "change the timeout for the entire script?" There should be no adverse side effects unless you're depending on the 60 second timeout for methods to fail.

Comment: @JimEvans, in my working example I need to set the timeout in the driver constructor. There is any other way to set the timeout just for a element? I could also set a longer timeout before the click and set the normal value after. I think that increase the timeout for the entire script would work, but don't seem to be the right solution.